# URL rewriting for nested directories in eXist-db

Tags: url-rewriting, exist-db

I want to separate secure pages into a directory.

The simplest scenario:

```
home/
  |-index.html
  |-controller.xql
  |-secure/
      |-authentication-test.html
      +-security.html
```

At the moment, everything works except escaping out of the `secure` directory/path. The problem is when I log in, every link on the `index.html` page becomes prefixed with the `/secure/` part of the url. This means after logging out I am not sent to `index.html` but to `/secure/index.html`, which does not exist. It reminds me of something like *context* or so. I am somehow **locked** in the nested directory, “the context has been changed”. I haven’t changed the `controller-config.xml` yet.

My controller:

```
xquery version "3.0";

import module namespace login="http://exist-db.org/xquery/login" at "resource:org/exist/xquery/modules/persistentlogin/login.xql";

declare variable $exist:path external;
declare variable $exist:resource external;
declare variable $exist:controller external;
declare variable $exist:prefix external;
declare variable $exist:root external;

declare variable $local:login_domain := "karolinum-x";
declare variable $local:user := $local:login_domain || '.user';

let $logout := request:get-parameter("logout", ())
let $set-user := login:set-user($local:login_domain, (), false())
return
if ($exist:path eq '') then
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <redirect url="{request:get-uri()}/"/>
    </dispatch>
else if ($exist:path eq "/") then
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <redirect url="index.html"/>
    </dispatch>
else if ($exist:path eq "/secure/authentication-test.html") then
    if (request:get-attribute("karolinum-x.user")) then
        <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
            <view>
                <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql">
                    <set-attribute name="isUser" value="true"/>
                    <set-attribute name="$exist:prefix" value="{$exist:prefix}"/>
                    <set-attribute name="$exist:controller" value="{$exist:controller}"/>
                </forward>
            </view>
            <error-handler>
                <forward url="{$exist:controller}/error-page.html" method="get"/>
                <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
            </error-handler>
        </dispatch>
    else
        <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/security.html"/>
            <view>
                <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql">
                    <set-attribute name="$exist:prefix" value="{$exist:prefix}"/>
                    <set-attribute name="$exist:controller" value="{$exist:controller}"/>
                    <set-header name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache"/>
                </forward>
            </view>
            <error-handler>
                <forward url="{$exist:controller}/error-page.html" method="get"/>
                <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
            </error-handler>
        </dispatch>
else if (ends-with($exist:resource, ".html")) then
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <view>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
        </view>
        <error-handler>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/error-page.html" method="get"/>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
        </error-handler>
    </dispatch>
(: Resource paths starting with $shared are loaded from the shared-resources app :)
else if (contains($exist:path, "/$shared/")) then
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <forward url="/shared-resources/{substring-after($exist:path, '/$shared/')}">
            <set-header name="Cache-Control" value="max-age=3600, must-revalidate"/>
        </forward>
    </dispatch>
else
    (: everything else is passed through :)
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <cache-control cache="yes"/>
    </dispatch>
```

Comment: The controller looks okay, actually. I'm having a hard time seeing the whole picture with just the controller and your description. If it's not too much trouble, could you post a .xar of a stripped down version of your app demonstrating the issue? (Unless someone else is able to spot the issue, of course!)

Comment: Of course, I will send it to you via PM.

Comment: Great, received, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're facing comes down to this: your main template, `templates/page.html`, contains menu items with relative links, so as you descend into sub-directories, the links break. This will happen in any other page where you use relative links that need to be displayed at various levels of URL hierarchy. Here is an excerpt from your `templates/page.html` showing relative links:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown" id="about">
        <a href="index.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown" id="test">
        <a href="test/url.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Test</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here, both `index.html` and `test/url.html` are relative.  So if you start at `index.html` click on the menu link to `test/url.html`, the new menu items are relative to the `test` directory, so clicking on either menu item will take you to `test/index.html` or `test/test/url.html` - and so on.  To overcome this issue, you have at least three choices:

(1) use hard-coded, absolute links, e.g., `/exist/apps/my-app/index.html` and `/exist/apps/my-app/test/url.html`.  This is simplest.

(2) use a method similar to the controller.xql's handling of `$shared`-prefixed URLs.  For example, you could make the links `$app/index.html`, and then add a conditional to controller.xql to process `$app`-prefixed URLs like `$app/index.html` or `$app/test/url.html`.  This leads to multiple URLs resolving to the same resource, so I don't particularly like this method, but it works.

or (3) use a templating call to a function like `app:fix-links`, as the hsg-shell app does. See https://github.com/eXistSolutions/hsg-shell/blob/master/modules/app.xqm#L62 and https://github.com/eXistSolutions/hsg-shell/blob/master/templates/site.html#L45. While this means prefixing all links that you want processed this way in the app with `$app`, it does give you tremendous flexibility for deeply nested URLs and future changes of app structure and name, etc.